# How to use a printf command to print a string array horizonatally in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to print:

```java
 String[] provinces = 
      { 
         "Ontario", 
         "Quebec", 
         "Nova Scotia",
         "New Brunswick", 
         "Manitoba", 
         "British Columbia",
         "Prince Edward Island"         
      };
```

using the following command:

```
for (String spiceTraders: provinces) {
       System.out.println("              " + spiceTraders);
   }
```

Now, this prints my output as I want but how do I do it with `printf`, just the way `println` command prints it and that is print vertically.

This is the desired output:

```
          Ontario
          Quebec
          Nova Scotia
          New Brunswick
          Manitoba
          British Columbia
          Prince Edward Island
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for method [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) which contains a link to the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use printf using %n to get the linefeed and %s to pass the String

```
    for (String spiceTraders: provinces) {
           System.out.printf("              %s%n", spiceTraders);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.printf("%s", "              " + String.join("\n              ", provinces) + "\n");
```

Comment: Thank you. Its looping, but I kind of get the idea of how it works now.